# Is there a way in flutter to generate Widgets in a List without using Listview , Gridview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

What I want to do is to put my Widgets in the List to a Stack. Every widget in the list will return a container with different alignment.

```
Container( alignment: Alignment(xValue,yValue))
```

My stack is as Follows:

```
stack(
children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(
width :MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
child: Container(
color:Colors.greenAccent,
child: ListView.builder(
           physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
           itemCount: widgetList.length,
           itemBuilder(BuildContext contet, int index){
                return widgetList[index]; })
))])
```

Here even though my containers appear in the Stack their positions are not the positions I wanted. Their alignment is done inside the listtile. What i want is to align those containers in the widgetlist inside the SizedBox.I could get it done as follows.

```
stack(
   children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
            width :MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Container( color: Colors.greenAccent)),
        widgetList[0],
        widgetList[1], ])
```

This way even if could get the widgets in the list to be at the need location it is not dynamic. I need help to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spread operator

```
Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
            width :MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Container( color: Colors.greenAccent)),
        ...widgetList,    // Note the three dots before the widgetList
])
```